# WP8 map overlay out of range error

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8, outofrangeexception

I have the following problem. I wrote this Fnction to add some Images as Icons to my Map on a Silverlight C# App for Windows Phone 8.

```
private void SpecialMapIcons()
{
    MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
    List<string[]> SpecialIcons = new List<string[]>();

    SpecialIcons.Add(new string[] { "icon0.png", "52.5", "13.5" });
    SpecialIcons.Add(new string[] { "icon1.png", "52.4", "13.4" });

    for (int i = 0; i < SpecialIcons.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] Icons = SpecialIcons[i];

        MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay()
        {
            GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(Icons[1]), Convert.ToDouble(Icons[2])),
            Content = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/icon/" + Icons[0], UriKind.Relative)),
                Width = 50,
                Height = 50,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            }
        };
        layer.Add(overlay);
    }
    Map.Layers.Add(layer);
}
```

And on Emulator it is working just fine but on Device i always get an out of range exception with an exapted value of -90 to 90 on the line where i am creating the overlay:

```
MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay()
```

i have no idea why this happens or what this value should mean. Does anyone have a hint how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the issue, i dont know why but silvelight on emulator can use the

Convert.ToDouble()

Function but the Device not. There the:

float.Parse(, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Function has to be used.